# Linking 2 columns, same table to a different table

Tags: sql

First time poster, a little background I am not the most experienced SQL user, most of my knowledge is self taught, but I really struggling to get the results I am looking for here so I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

In the simplest form
I have a table that has all of our **Item_ID**'s. Each of those item numbers has a **Universal_ID** associated with it stored in the same table structure. Most of the time these numbers match, except in the example below **Item_ID** 2 has a **Universal_ID** of 1

```
Item_ID | Univeral_ID
   1    | 1
   2    | 1
```

We then have an inventory table, which can be linked on the ItemID to show the QTY

```
Item_ID | Item_Qty | Item_Code
   1    | 10       | 2/2/2021
   1    | 20       | 2/3/2021
   2    | 30       | 2/2/2021
```

If the **Item_ID** and **Universal_ID** are the same, it is quite easy to obtain the inventory
However I am struggling to get inventories for both when they do not match.

For example, if I wanted to find the QTY of **Item_ID** 1, I would be returned 2 results

```
Item_ID | Item_Qty | Item_Code
   1    | 10       | 2/2/2021
   1    | 20       | 2/3/2021
```

***Problem:*** if I specifically am interested in **Item_ID** 2, how can I link it to the inventory table, to see not only **Item_ID** 2's qty available and also **Item_ID** 1's qty available since the **Universal_ID** does not match the **Item_ID**

So I would like the results to be just like the 2nd block of code I posted.

```
Item_ID | Item_Qty | Item_Code
  1    | 10       | 2/2/2021
  1    | 20       | 2/3/2021
  2    | 30       | 2/2/2021
```

What is the best way to set up views or my select query to make this happen? If I need to add any more info I can!

Comment: Hmm, I don't get the problem. Seems to me like the `universal_id` plays no role at all. Just join on the `item_id` and you should get what you want?

Comment: Are you able to reproduce your tables here: http://sqlfiddle.com/ ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `left join` and filtering:

```
select i.*
from inventory i left join
     universal u
     on i.item_id = u.item_id
where 1 in (u.universal_id, i.item_id);
```